# In R, How to make a function that finds if there is a matching pairs?

Tags: r

I want to make a function that can detect if there is a matching pair of numbers. I want to simulate x and y many times to see the # of matches occurring using a function.

```
x<-sample(1:6,6)
y<-sample(1:6,6)
x;y
```

For example, I have x<- c(2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1)and y<- c(2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3). Numbers 2 and 6 matches in order. There are 2 pairs. If there is no match between x and y, it should be just 0. I can use sum(x==y) to find for one example of x and y.

How can I make a function that finds number of identical pairs for many x and y?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
f<-function(n,k) {
  sapply(1:k, \(i) sum(sample(n) == sample(n)))
}
```

where `k` is the number of iterations and `n` is the range (in your case 6)

Example Usage:

```
f(n=6, k=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R the following function would do the trick. The length of vector is given by the `size` argument, and the number of trials is given by `n`

```r
n_pairs <- function(size, n) {
  colSums(replicate(n, sample(size)) == replicate(n, sample(size)))
}
```

So, for example we can see:

```r
set.seed(1)

n_pairs(size = 6, n = 5)
#> [1] 2 0 1 1 1

hist(n_pairs(6, 100), breaks = 0:6)
```

[image]

```r
mean(n_pairs(6, 1000))
#> [1] 1.013
```

Note though that R already has the function `rbinom`, which can achieve the same result with:

```r
rbinom(n, size, 1/size)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one (removed first answer):

```
x<- c(2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1) 
y<- c(2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3)

lst = list(x,y)

pairs <- outer(lst,lst,Vectorize(function(x,y){x[x==y]}))

pairs[1,2]
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with `dplyr` package

```
 require(tidyverse)

x <- c(2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1)
y <- c(2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3)

df <- tibble(x = x,
             y = y) %>%
  mutate(pair = case_when(x == y ~ "PAIR",
                          TRUE ~ "NOT"))
```

The dataset:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y pair 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     2     2 PAIR 
2     5     1 NOT  
3     6     6 PAIR 
4     4     5 NOT  
5     3     4 NOT  
6     1     3 NOT
```

Filtering:

```
df %>%  
  filter(pair == "PAIR")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      x     y pair 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     2     2 PAIR 
2     6     6 PAIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this give you what you want? Make a table out of the values that are paired.

```r
table(x[x==y])
```

```r
x <- sample(1:6,1000, TRUE)
y <- sample(1:6,1000, TRUE)
  
table(x[x==y])
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 37 26 32 28 30 33
```